# ERROR: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread in Loop

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchttpclient

Im getting a not so rare error, which happens to many, the thing is that im not using threads in my app. Its just a loop, one task after the other, so i dont understand why im getting out of threads.

Basically for each line of the text file i make a GET request to an api, so i obtain some json data...

Here is the error log:

```
106
105
104
103
102
ene 06, 2016 4:08:39 PM org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture
ADVERTENCIA: An exception was thrown by ChannelFutureListener.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1368)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.start(AbstractNioWorker.java:160)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.executeInIoThread(AbstractNioWorker.java:306)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.executeInIoThread(NioWorker.java:38)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.executeInIoThread(AbstractNioWorker.java:290)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.executeInIoThread(NioWorker.java:38)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioChannelSink.execute(AbstractNioChannelSink.java:34)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaughtLater(Channels.java:504)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:47)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:821)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:194)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener$2.operationComplete(ChannelFutureListener.java:52)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:399)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:385)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:352)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:404)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:361)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ERROR en getML():/orders/1045232034
com.mercadolibre.sdk.MeliException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: unable to create new native thread to https://api.mercadolibre.com/orders/1045232034?access_token=APP_USR-1978251743308541-010613-c60e34a2a34d0fd5b8c936ccfb3e3732__K_I__-113746522
    at com.nubimedia.app.ml.Melis.get(Melis.java:264)
    at com.nubimedia.app.ml.Melis.getML(Melis.java:168)
    at com.nubimedia.app.ModelML.encontrarMailsLog(ModelML.java:217)
    at com.nubimedia.app.Pruebas.main(Pruebas.java:11)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: unable to create new native thread to https://api.mercadolibre.com/orders/1045232034?access_token=APP_USR-1978251743308541-010613-c60e34a2a34d0fd5b8c936ccfb3e3732__K_I__-113746522
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponseFuture.abort(NettyResponseFuture.java:297)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:104)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:399)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:390)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:352)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:404)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:361)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:277)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: unable to create new native thread to https://api.mercadolibre.com/orders/1045232034?access_token=APP_USR-1978251743308541-010613-c60e34a2a34d0fd5b8c936ccfb3e3732__K_I__-113746522
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:100)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1368)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.start(AbstractNioWorker.java:160)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.register(AbstractNioWorker.java:131)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:401)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:361)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:277)
    ... 3 more
Hubo un error
101
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1368)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.jdk.JDKAsyncHttpProvider.execute(JDKAsyncHttpProvider.java:159)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.jdk.JDKAsyncHttpProvider.execute(JDKAsyncHttpProvider.java:121)
    at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient$BoundRequestBuilder.execute(AsyncHttpClient.java:234)
    at com.nubimedia.app.ml.Melis.get(Melis.java:262)
    at com.nubimedia.app.ml.Melis.getML(Melis.java:168)
    at com.nubimedia.app.ModelML.encontrarMailsLog(ModelML.java:217)
    at com.nubimedia.app.Pruebas.main(Pruebas.java:11)
```

And here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MeliException {

        ModelML.getInstance().encontrarMailsLog(731);
    }


public void encontrarMailsLog(int max) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/fabrizioguespe/Downloads/catalina.out"));
    Set<String> resources=new TreeSet<String>();

    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            if(line.equals("Nueva Request!")){
                String cliente=br.readLine();
                String resource=br.readLine();
                resources.add(cliente+"-"+resource);
            }
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }

    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
    Log.log(resources.size()+" Para procesar");
    int i=resources.size();
    for(String s: resources){
        i--;
        Log.log(i+"");
        if(max>0)
            if(i>max)continue;
        String cliente=s.split("-")[0];
        String resource=s.split("-")[1];
        //Log.log("Cliente: "+cliente+" "+resource);
        ModelML.getInstance().procesarRequest(Melis.getML(resource, null,cliente,false),resource);
    }
}
```

UPDATED: As suggested, and makes sense. I may be doing async request, using the SDK provided by the API

Here is the class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import com.mercadolibre.sdk.AuthorizationFailure;
import com.mercadolibre.sdk.MeliException;
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.BoundRequestBuilder;
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig;
import com.ning.http.client.FluentStringsMap;
import com.ning.http.client.Response;
import com.nubimedia.app.ModelML;
import com.nubimedia.app.util.HibernateUtil;
import com.nubimedia.app.util.Log;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class Melis {
    public static String apiUrl = "https://api.mercadolibre.com";
    private String accessToken;
    private String refreshToken;
    private Long clientId;
    private String clientSecret;

    //public static Map<String,UserML> clientes=new HashMap<String,UserML>();


    public static UserML getCliente(String id) {//Solo para inicializar la aplicacion
        Session s=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        Query query = s.createQuery("from UserML where id = :id");
        query.setString("id", id);
        UserML q = (UserML) query.uniqueResult();
        s.flush();
        s.getTransaction().commit();
        s.close();
        return q;

    }
    public static List<UserML> getClientes() {
        Session s=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        Query query = s.createQuery("from UserML");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<UserML> q = (List<UserML>) query.list();
        s.flush();
        s.getTransaction().commit();
        s.close();
        return q;

    }
    public static String preguntarML(String item,String pregunta,String idcliente){

        UserML cliente=getCliente(idcliente);
        if(cliente==null)return null;

        Melis m = new Melis(Long.parseLong(ModelML.ml_appid),ModelML.ml_secret,cliente.getToken(),cliente.getToken());
        String params="{\"text\":\""+pregunta.trim()+"\",\"item_id\":\""+item+"\"}";
        String json=Melis.postML("/questions/"+item+"?access_token="+m.getAccessToken(), null, cliente, params);
        return json;
    }

    public static String postML(String resource,FluentStringsMap params,UserML cliente,String json){
        try {
            Melis m = new Melis(Long.parseLong(ModelML.ml_appid),ModelML.ml_secret,cliente.getToken(),cliente.getRefresh_token());
            if(params==null){
                params = new FluentStringsMap();
                params.add("access_token", m.getAccessToken());

            }
            Response respuesta = m.post(resource, params,json);
            String jsons=respuesta.getResponseBody();
            //jsons=new String(json.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");

            return jsons;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.log("ERROR en getML():"+resource);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static String getUserId(String json){
        try{
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

            JsonObject venta= (JsonObject)parser.parse(json);
            if(venta.isJsonNull())return null;
            return venta.get("id").getAsString();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.log("ERROR al parsear json VENTA mercadolibre: ");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String setToken(String token,String refresh_token,String idcliente) {
        UserML a=getCliente(idcliente);
        if(a==null)return null;
        a.setToken(token);
        a.setRefresh_token(refresh_token);
        a.setLast_modif(new Date());
        Session s=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        s.saveOrUpdate(a);
        s.flush();
        s.getTransaction().commit();
        s.close();

        return null;

    }
    public static String getML2(String resource){
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(apiUrl+resource);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) 
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());

        return response.getEntity(String.class);

    }
    public static String remokeAccess(String idcliente){
        try {
            UserML cliente=getCliente(idcliente);
            if(cliente==null)return null;
            String resource="/users/"+cliente+"/applications/"+ModelML.ml_appid+"?access_token="+cliente.getToken();

            Melis m = new Melis(Long.parseLong(ModelML.ml_appid),ModelML.ml_secret,cliente.getToken());
            FluentStringsMap params = new FluentStringsMap();
            params.add("access_token", m.getAccessToken());

            Response respuesta = m.delete(resource, params);
            String json=respuesta.getResponseBody();
            json=new String(json.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");

            return json;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.log("ERROR en removkeAccess():"+idcliente);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
    public static String getML(String resource,FluentStringsMap params,String idcliente,boolean access_final){
        try {
            UserML cliente=getCliente(idcliente);
            if(cliente==null)return null;
            Melis m = new Melis(Long.parseLong(ModelML.ml_appid),ModelML.ml_secret,cliente.getToken(),cliente.getRefresh_token());
            if(params==null){
                params = new FluentStringsMap();
                params.add("access_token", m.getAccessToken());

            }
            if(access_final)resource+="?access_token="+cliente.getToken();
            Response respuesta = m.get(resource, params);
            String json=respuesta.getResponseBody();
            json=new String(json.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");

            return json;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.log("ERROR en getML():"+resource);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private AsyncHttpClient http;
    {
        AsyncHttpClientConfig cf = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
                 .setUserAgent("MELIJAVASDK0.0.1").build();
        http = new AsyncHttpClient(cf);
    } 


    public Melis(Long clientId, String clientSecret ) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }




    public Melis(Long clientId, String clientSecret, String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }

    public Melis(Long clientId, String clientSecret, String accessToken,  String refreshToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return this.accessToken;
    }



    public Response get(String path) throws MeliException {
    return get(path, new FluentStringsMap());
    }

    private BoundRequestBuilder prepareGet(String path, FluentStringsMap params) {
    return http.prepareGet(apiUrl + path)
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .setQueryParameters(params);
    }

    private BoundRequestBuilder prepareDelete(String path,
        FluentStringsMap params) {
    return http.prepareDelete(apiUrl + path)
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .setQueryParameters(params);
    }

    private BoundRequestBuilder preparePost(String path,
        FluentStringsMap params, String body) {
    return http.preparePost(apiUrl + path)
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .setQueryParameters(params)
        .setHeader("ContentType", "application/json").setBody(body)
        .setBodyEncoding("UTF8");
    }

    private BoundRequestBuilder preparePut(String path,
        FluentStringsMap params, String body) {
    return http.preparePut(apiUrl + path)
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .setQueryParameters(params)
        .setHeader("ContentType", "application/json").setBody(body)
        .setBodyEncoding("UTF8");
    }

    private BoundRequestBuilder preparePost(String path, FluentStringsMap params) {
    return http.preparePost(apiUrl + path)
        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        .setQueryParameters(params);
    }

    public Response get(String path, FluentStringsMap params)  throws MeliException {
        BoundRequestBuilder r = prepareGet(path, params);

        Response response;
        try {
            response = r.execute().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MeliException(e);
        }
        if (params.containsKey("access_token") && this.hasRefreshToken() && response.getStatusCode() == 401) {
            try {
                refreshAccessToken();
            } catch (AuthorizationFailure e1) {
                Log.log("ERROR al refrescar token");
                return response;
            }
            params.replace("access_token", this.accessToken);
            r = prepareGet(path, params);

            try {
                response = r.execute().get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new MeliException(e);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    public void refreshAccessToken() throws AuthorizationFailure {
        FluentStringsMap params = new FluentStringsMap();
        params.add("grant_type", "refresh_token");
        params.add("client_id", String.valueOf(this.clientId));
        params.add("client_secret", this.clientSecret);
        params.add("refresh_token", this.refreshToken);
        BoundRequestBuilder req = preparePost("/oauth/token", params);

        parseToken(req);
    }

    public String getAuthUrl(String callback) {
    try {
        return "https://auth.mercadolibre.com.ar/authorization?response_type=code&client_id="
            + this.clientId
            + "&redirect_uri="
            + URLEncoder.encode(callback, "UTF8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return "https://auth.mercadolibre.com.ar/authorization?response_type=code&client_id="
            + this.clientId + "&redirect_uri=" + callback;
    }
    }

   public String authorize(String code, String redirectUri) throws AuthorizationFailure {
        FluentStringsMap params = new FluentStringsMap();

        params.add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        params.add("client_id", String.valueOf(this.clientId));
        params.add("client_secret", this.clientSecret);
        params.add("code", code);
        params.add("redirect_uri", redirectUri);

        BoundRequestBuilder r = preparePost("/oauth/token", params);

        return parseToken(r);
    }

    private String parseToken(BoundRequestBuilder r) throws AuthorizationFailure {
        Response response = null;
        String responseBody = "";
        try {
            response = r.execute().get();
            responseBody = response.getResponseBody();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new AuthorizationFailure(e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new AuthorizationFailure(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AuthorizationFailure(e);
        }

        JsonParser p = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject object;

        try {
            object = p.parse(responseBody).getAsJsonObject();
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            throw new AuthorizationFailure(responseBody);
        }

        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            this.accessToken = object.get("access_token").getAsString();
            this.refreshToken = object.get("refresh_token").getAsString();
            String user_ID = object.get("user_id").getAsString();
            Melis.setToken(this.accessToken, this.refreshToken,user_ID);//PERSISTO
            return object.toString();
        } else return object.get("message").getAsString();
    }

    private boolean hasRefreshToken() {
    return this.refreshToken != null && !this.refreshToken.isEmpty();
    }

    public Response post(String path, FluentStringsMap params, String body)
        throws MeliException {
    BoundRequestBuilder r = preparePost(path, params, body);

    Response response;
    try {
        response = r.execute().get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
    }
    if (params.containsKey("access_token") && this.hasRefreshToken()    && response.getStatusCode() == 401) {
        try {
        refreshAccessToken();
        } catch (AuthorizationFailure e1) {
        return response;
        }
        params.replace("access_token", this.accessToken);
        r = preparePost(path, params, body);

        try {
        response = r.execute().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
        }
    }
    return response;
    }

    public Response put(String path, FluentStringsMap params, String body)
        throws MeliException {
    BoundRequestBuilder r = preparePut(path, params, body);

    Response response;
    try {
        response = r.execute().get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
    }
    if (params.containsKey("access_token") && this.hasRefreshToken()
        && response.getStatusCode() == 401) {
        try {
        refreshAccessToken();
        } catch (AuthorizationFailure e1) {
        return response;
        }
        params.replace("access_token", this.accessToken);
        r = preparePut(path, params, body);

        try {
        response = r.execute().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
        }
    }
    return response;
    }

    public Response delete(String path, FluentStringsMap params)
        throws MeliException {
    BoundRequestBuilder r = prepareDelete(path, params);

    Response response;
    try {
        response = r.execute().get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
    }
    if (params.containsKey("access_token") && this.hasRefreshToken()
        && response.getStatusCode() == 401) {
        try {
        refreshAccessToken();
        } catch (AuthorizationFailure e1) {
        return response;
        }
        params.replace("access_token", this.accessToken);
        r = prepareDelete(path, params);

        try {
        response = r.execute().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MeliException(e);
        }
    }
    return response;
    }

    public BoundRequestBuilder head(String path) {
    return null;
    }

    public BoundRequestBuilder options(String path) {
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception message is clear enough. What do you understand about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: AsyncHttpClient author here

First, I don't know why the answer above was validated, it's wrong.

I suspect that you're creating tons of Melis instances. But you completely missed the point that an AsyncHttpClient instance must be used as a singleton (except for very specific use cases).

As every Melis instance creates its own AsyncHttpClient instance, you end up creating tons of them, and you blow off resource usage.

Note that your AsyncHttpClient instance(s) must be closed when you shut your application down so underlying resources get freed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a memory problem, but an operating system resource problem,this has nothing to do with programming, or linux.